# What does the vector input in MATLAB fnplt do?

Tags: matlab

[The documentation of `fnplt`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fnplt.html) says

> A vector of the form [a,b], to indicate the interval over which to
>   plot the univariate function in f.

So I thought vector `[a, b]` means plotting the part of spline curve `s` that falls into the interval `[a, b]`. But the following experiments don't seem to support my this interpretation.

Running

```
x = [0.16;0.15;0.25;0.48;0.67];
y = [0.77;0.55;0.39;0.22;0.21];
spcv = cscvn([x, y].');
fnplt(spcv); % plot the full curve
hold on;
fnplt(spcv,[0.3,0.4],'r'); % plot the "[0.3, 0.4] part" in RED
fnplt(spcv,[1,2],'g'); % plot the "[1, 2] part" in GREEN
```

gives me this

[image]

How do I make sense of the results?

Comment: Your function for your spline isn't a function of x and y, it's a function of some other parameter (such as arclength), so the vector you provide is *that* parameter, not `x` or `y`

Comment: Thanks! Then is there a way to plot only part of the spline? Like the segment between point 1 and point 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spline, although constructed from known `x` and `y` points, is no longer a function of `x` and `y`. Instead, it is a function of the arc length along the spline. So the vector that you provide as the second input to `fnplt` is the range of *that* parameter and not `x` and `y`.

If you want to determine the correct ranges to pass to `fnplt` such that each piece of the spline (between successive input points) is a different color, you can use the output of `cscvn` to determine the values of the parameter at each input point.

```
spcv = cscvn([x, y].');

%          form: 'pp'
%        breaks: [0 0.4693 0.9037 1.4385 1.8746]   <---- These are the parameter values
%         coefs: [8x4 double]
%        pieces: 4
%         order: 4
%           dim: 2
```

Specifically, we can use the `breaks` field to determine the parameter value corresponding to each input point and we can loop through these values to plot each section independently with `fnplt`.

```
colors = 'rgbc'

for k = 1:(numel(x) - 1)
    fnplt(spcv, spcv.breaks([k k+1]), colors(k));
    hold on
end
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely beautiful. Many thanks! In this toy case, I have 5 input points and end up with 5 break points. But in my real case, I have n input points, but n-1 break points. Hmmm, this causes problems to my for loop. Is there an explanation why this happens?

Comment: No. From some experiments I just did, there are cases where I only have n-2 break points too.

Comment: @SibbsGambling It may be worth setting up the `for` loop to instead just loop through the `breaks` and then you can visualize what is happening.